# How to calculate standard deviation on percentages?

Tags: statistics

The variance on the difference between two random variables can be calculated as:
$Var(X-Y) = \sigma^2_X - \sigma^2_Y - 2 Cov(X,Y)$. Numerically, i got the following values:

$\sigma^2_X = 0.03$ (3%)

$\sigma^2_Y = 0.05$ (5%)

$Cov(X,Y) = 0.00025$

**Calculation:**

$Var(X-Y) = 0.03^2 + 0.05^2 - 2 * 0.00025 = 0.0029$

However, I get another result if I multiply by 100 %

$3^2 + 5^2 - 2 * 0.00025 = 33.9995$

How do I calculate this correctly?

Comment: "$Y = 40 \% , X = 60 \%$". What is the meaning of that ?

Comment: I deleted it. I wrote it on accident.

Comment: And what next ?

Comment: Notice that the square of $3\%$ is not $9\%$.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that $Var(X-Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)-2cov(X,Y)$.

Thus $Var(X-Y)=0.03+0.02-2\cdot 0.00025=0.0495$

There is no need to multiply anything by 100. Also 0.02 and 0.03 musn´t be squared, because they are already the values of the variances.